# How to change h1 tittle when clicked/make the section centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on some simple questions as practice for my exam, but most of the questions don't have any answers for me to check if I don't know. There is one I'm really unsure about, so I thaught I'd check here. The question is:

Suppose we have an HTML document that contains these two lines:

```
<Body>
<H1 title = "When this is clicked, the section changes"> Title </ h1> 
<P id = "first" title = "When this is clicked, the title is centered"> First section: Original version. </ P>
</ Body>
```

Type the code that would change the look of this page so that:

• When you click on the h1 title, the section changes from "First section: Original Version" to "First section: modified version ".

• When you click on the section, the position of the title changes and gets centered.

Hope someone can help learn me this so I have an answer if something similar shows up on my exam:)

Comment: Please try to solve the problem yourself first. If you get stuck, include the relevant parts of your code in your question, along with a description of the expected and the actual behavior and any error messages you may be getting.

Comment: Hi if any below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var first = document.querySelector('#first');

h1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  first.innerText = 'First section: modified version.';
});

first.addEventListener('click', function() {
  h1.style.textAlign = 'center';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$(document).on("click", "h1", function() {
  $(this).css("text-align", "center");
})
```

```css
p, h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 title="When this is clicked, the section changes"> Title </h1>
<p id="first" title="When this is clicked, the title is centered"> First section: Original version. </p>
```

Comment: jQuery was not mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should be able to find everything on Google. But to help you out, this is what the answer should be:

```js
var heading = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
var section = document.getElementById("first");

heading.addEventListener("click", function() {
    section.innerText = "First section: modified version";
});

section.addEventListener("click", function() {
    heading.setAttribute("style", "text-align: center");
});
```

```html
<h1 title="When this is clicked, the section changes">Title</h1>
<p id="first" title="When this is clicked, the title is centered">First section: Original version.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Please correct your `html` markup to standards and add some javascript code. Check below snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'h1', function(){
  $('#first').text('First section: Modified version.');
});
$(document).on('click', '#first', function(){
  $('h1').css('text-align','center');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 title = "When this is clicked, the section changes"> Title </h1> 
<P id = "first" title = "When this is clicked, the title is centered"> First section: Original version. </ P>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea why you're being downvoted here. From what I gather you've tried your best on all your assigned questions and this one happened to stump you...

Anyways.. this question has a few different problems that need to be solved for you to complete the question. I'm going to try to break these down into the components, and then explain the pieces that help us get to where you want to be.

## Question 1

Thinking through this a bit, here are the following steps to solve your problem.

1. Find a way to "listen" for a "click event" on the `<h1>` element.
2. Find a way to change the text within the `<p>` element to the desired text when the `<h1>` element is clicked.

There are some substeps buried in this but this should get us started.

To solve this issue, we'll need to find a way to select elements on a page. A Google search yields a few methods to do this in vanilla JS based solely on the code you've given.

- Query Selectors: `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`
- Tag selectors: `document.getElementsByTagName`

There are many others as well, but using only the code that you've supplied, and assuming we're not allowed to add class attributes or anything, we'll roll with the above choices.

The selectors above all return HTML "nodes" from the page. You can think of a HTML nodes as objects that make up an HTML page. They have all sorts of properties and we can perform many operations on them.

Your best bet is to use the first suggestion, `document.querySelector` because it returns a single HTML node based on the passed selector. Be careful though. If we had more than one of the same element, it would only return the first which isn't at all useful.

Here's some documentation you can read and a few examples to help you understand how it works.

[document.querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

So now we have a way of selecting the `<h1>` element on the page.

`document.querySelector(h1);`

Now, we need a way to listen for events. A search of "listening for events in vanilla JS" would bring you to the addEventListener method, which allows us to listen for events on a given HTML element.

[eventListener documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Now we can put these two together and we have an `<h1>` element that listens for events. I'm going to skip ahead a bit and fill in the function so we have.

```
let title = document.querySelector('h1');

title.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('I just clicked the title');
});
```

If you plug that in and click the title, you'll see a modal pop up indicating that you clicked the title. One step down.

Now, we have to find a way to change the "text content" of the `<p>` element to the desired text. To do this, we first need to select the `<p>` element and store it in a variable. You now know how to do this so I'll leave you to it.

Now that we have the reference to the node we want to modify, we need to change a property of that node related to the text. A Google search of this will return a few different properties, but I'm going to nudge you in the right direction and let you know you want the `elem.textContent` property.

**Putting this all together, here's the code I have that works and satisfies your requirements for the first question.**

```
let headerTxt = document.querySelector('h1');
let sectionTxt = document.querySelector('p');

headerTxt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sectionTxt.textContent = 'First section: modified version';
});
```

## Question 2

Some similarities from the first question here. We need to...

1. Select both the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements on the page (DONE)
2. add a click event listener to the `<p>` element that centers the `<h1>` element.

We can skip the first piece since we did that in question 1. I'm also going to skip adding an event listener to the `<p>` since we did something similar to that in the first question.

After adding the event listener, we need a way to change the text-alignment of some text in an HTML element.

A Google search brings us to the textAlign CSS property which we can modify using JS.

[textAlign](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_textalign.asp)

## Putting this all together, here's the complete solution

```js
let headerTxt = document.querySelector('h1');
let sectionTxt = document.querySelector('p');

headerTxt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sectionTxt.textContent = 'First section: modified version';
});

sectionTxt.addEventListener('click', function() {
  headerTxt.style.textAlign = 'center';
});
```

```html
<body>
<h1 title = "When this is clicked, the section changes"> Title </h1> 
<p id = "first" title = "When this is clicked, the title is centered"> First section: Original version. </p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps man. One takeaway of advice I have for you is get used to searching and get used to reading documentation. I'm a beginner too and I've figured that out quickly lol.

Good luck!